# Routing electrical wire when existing hole is too tight

Tags: electrical, wiring

Check out the wires running
[image]

I tried to add an extra wire so my powder room light and fan would be on separate switches but even after removing the staples so the existing wires could move about a bit, I just can't fit an extra wire.

Removing it all and expanding the hole doesn't seem efficient. I don't have access to where they run to. (Not without removing cables / having to re-run them)

Instead, can I drill a new hole parallel to it like this? It' the only thing I can think to do:[image]

Comment: Are the existing cables all proper NM cables? (They look a bit...off in the photos posted, but I can't tell for sure without a clear closeup shot)

Comment: Yes, they all are NM - sorry for potato quality pic :-)

Comment: Good -- I was thinking they were all cordage for a bit there, haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can drill extra holes just make sure you don't nick the existing wires.